# How to edit a WFS layer with leaflet draw

Tags: jquery, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I have spend more than 4 hours trying to figure out how I can do this.
I use Leaflet and Leaflet Draw in order to draw news features on my map.

Now I want to be able to edit features of an existing WFS layer (coming from geoserver).

I have searched a lot all around internet and I can not find a clear example of how to make my WFS layer editable.

This is what I do based on the example from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ddproxy/suL12z93/3/):

```
// intialize the drawItems and add it to the map 
var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
 map_add.addLayer(drawnItems);
// initialize the controls  (only editing) and add it to the map
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
          draw: {
              position: 'topleft'
          },
          edit: {
              featureGroup: drawnItems,
              edit: true
              }
          }
      });
map_add.addControl(drawControl);

url_string = "thats my url"
// make wfs request and add the layer in the drawItems 
var geojson = $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "json",
          url: url_string,
          success: function (response) {
             drawnItems.addLayer(L.geoJson(response));
          }
        });
```

The layer is displayed on the map. But when I click the edit button (of the leaflet draw plugin) I get a:

```
      Cannot read property 'enable' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?
Please advise! 
If I follow the example in the link I provided it works. But the guy there he uses data inline with his code. I need to use the layer from the WFS request.

Comment: any possibility of showing us your live demo?

Comment: For the record, it looks like this post is the continuation of the following: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202701/how-to-edit-specific-geometry-on-leaflet-layer, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203742/how-to-edit-a-wfs-layer-with-leaflet-draw and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203540/how-to-edit-an-existing-layer-using-leaflet, with a working solution in that last one I believe. In short, it looks to be a matter of Layer Groups nested in `drawnItems`, which cannot be handled by Leaflet.draw. So just get rid of groups and directly add non-group layers.